# Rails form: get object method by string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I'm trying to create a dynamic form where I get the object methods by a String from the columns list.

In my view I have the following code:

```
  <% Contact.columns.each do |column| %>
      <% if column.name.in? ["id", *Contact.accessible_attributes] %>
          <%= f.select column.name, options_for_select(@contacts.first.keys, :include_blank => :true) %>
      <%end%>
    <%end%>
```

This will give me errors, so I would like how can I bind a String to an method in a view.

```
undefined method `id' for #<ContactImport:0x00000003686598>
```

Comment: What values are in the columns list?

Comment: @JoeFrambach the values are just Strings. I've edited the code to allow only fields that are permitted to change.

Comment: What errors are you receiving?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to use the select_tag instead.

```
<%= form_for(@contact_import) do |f| %>
  <% Contact.columns.each do |column| %>
  <% if column.name.in? *Contact.accessible_attributes << 'id' %>
  <%= label_tag column.name %>
<%= select_tag column.name, options_for_select(@contacts.first.keys), :include_blank => true %>
  <%end%>
<%end%>
<%= submit_tag 'Submit' %>
<%end%>
```

This way I can set the fields name based on the String from column.name.

Answer (score 1):

I think the splat operator is causing you issues. `Contact.accessible_attributes` returns an `#<ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::WhiteList: {}>` object, which a splat evidently cannot operate on.

Instead, render the object into an array using `to_a` and append `id` to that array (`<<` will mutate in place).

```
<% Contact.columns.each do |column| %>
    <% if column.name.in? Contact.accessible_attributes.to_a << 'id' %>
        <%= f.select column.name, options_for_select(@contacts.first.keys, :include_blank => :true) %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip on << operator, but the main problem was to create the form fields based on a String.